# Highcharts with angularjs without jquery

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Highcharts documentation says that it has some dependencies that can be met with jquery, prototype or mootools.  Is there a way to use highcharts/highstock with angularjs without bringing in any of these other libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.

[Highcharts relased a Standalone version](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/58-highcharts-standalone-framework)

Check it out, I think it's a more direct answer to your question than what was posted here.

Also, there's an Angular Directive for Highcharts:

[Highcharts-ng by PabloJim](http://pablojim.github.io/highcharts-ng/)

Also, for more info check out a similar question: [Highcharts in AngularJs without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140764/highcharts-in-angularjs-without-jquery)

Comment: Please explain links if you are posting an answer.

Comment: Done, hope this fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Angular includes it's own "jqLite" which is a subset of jQuery functions that were necessary (or at least made it much easier) for Angular itself to work.  Including jQuery itself will override the jQLite built in to Angular (but they should work fine together and have for me, I'm only using jQuery for ng-grid currently).

> Does Angular use the jQuery library?
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if
>   it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped.
>   If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to
>   its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

I've also been looking at charting solutions that will blend well with Angular and have started playing with d3js
http://d3js.org/

Basics of D3js
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html

AngularJS D3JS Directive Writing
http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3.html

D3 essentially gives you a toolkit of functions that help to scale values to build a chart from scratch and has built in interpolation for transitions between data sets.  There seem to be lots of cool examples but to build from svg or html elements into your desired chart from scratch is probably extensive work.

For something a little more pre-built and I believe without external dependencies either is Google Charts
https://developers.google.com/chart/

AngularJS Google Charts Directive
http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/