# Highcharts in AngularJs without jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts

Is there any directive for highcharts where you don't need the full jQuery? This ones seem's the most popular at the moment but I can't get it work without jQuery: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Is it possible to write a highcharts directive and only using the light version of jQuery that is included with angular?

If I do have to include the full jQuery, will it affect the loading time/performance of my app signifigantly?

Comment: Highcharts-ng does not require jquery. Just use Highcharts standalone framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not hard to build a directive that wraps the existing javascript library.

This is code for a highchart directive. It's very simple.

```
app.directive("highcharts", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      var options = scope.$eval(attrs.highcharts);
      options.chart.renderTo = el[0];
      new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
  };
})
```

Full demo is here. http://plnkr.co/edit/iN8TAMKyHIyN4F44iJ0U?p=preview

My answer to you is, if you like https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

- just add [standalone-framework](https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/js/adapters/standalone-framework.src.js) instead of full jQuery.
- if not, like me :), 
  build your own like the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/iN8TAMKyHIyN4F44iJ0U?p=preview) provided. it's not that hard.

BTW, This is the [page](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/58-highcharts-standalone-framework) Highcharts introduces their standalone framework.

Comment: Had missed that they had release a stand alone version. Truly perfect for angular. 32k is saved when I don't need Jquery. Thx for the help and demo provided!

Comment: You can even make that chart dragable: http://plnkr.co/edit/oTLE11tQIHvpQieGYGGu?p=preview

Comment: How can i redraw the chart using this method? It doesn't get updated when the values change.

Answer (score 0):

highchart is great, but currently even the Standalone Framework for Highcharts comes bundled with a jQuery adapter that can't be removed, and this is not so good if your plan is develop a mobile app